# How do I include a space in the delimiter of a FOR /F (batch file)

Tags: batch-file, command, whitespace, delimiter

The following command creates folders based on the part of a filename before a delimiter (in this case, a dash, or `-`):

```
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\Users\T\Source"
set "DestDir=C:\Users\T\Dest"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\*-*.jpg" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "eol=| tokens=1 delims=-" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        md "%DestDir%\%%B" 2>nul
        REM move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%B\"
    )
)

endlocal
```

Specifically, the delimiter command is here:

`delims=-`

But I need to include a space in the delimiter, both before and after the dash. How would I include a space in `delims`?

Comment: a delimiter is a set of single chars, not a string. `"Delims=ab` splits at every `a` and at every `b`.

Comment: @Stephan I wasn't aware. Is there a way to modify the existing script to take a string rather than a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign the file name to an environmental variable you can then use string substitution to manipulate that variable. In the first substitution you can remove the first part of the file name by using a wildcard with the string delimiter.  This will give you the ending portion of the file name.  Now that you have the ending portion of the file name you can turn around and use the string delimiter and the ending portion of the file name to be removed from the original file name.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\Users\T\Source"
set "DestDir=C:\Users\T\Dest"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\*-*.jpg" 2^>nul') do (
    set "string=%%~A"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    SET "end=!string:* - =!"
    FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ("!end!") do set "begin=!string: - %%~G=!"
    md "%DestDir%\!begin!" 2>nul
    REM move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%DestDir%\!begin!\"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the delimiting string with a single-char delimiter on-the-fly. I used `|`, because it's not valid in a filename and so is unique.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\Users\T\Source"
set "DestDir=C:\Users\T\Dest"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\*-*.jpg" 2^>nul') do (
    set "string=%%~A"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%G IN ("!string: - =|!") do (
      echo md "%DestDir%\%%G" 2>nul
      echo 1. move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%G\%%~nxA"
      echo 2. move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%G\%%~nxH"
      endlocal
    )
)
```

This code doesn't do anything on your disk, because I disarmed changing commands by just echoing them. Remove the `echo` before the `move` command and the `echo 1.` **or** the `echo 2.` (just remove the line you don't want/need). The first one leaves the filename intact, the second one shortens it to the second part (the first part is converted to the foldername anyway)